# Async database function executed on each panel.Paint() windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form application with multiple tabs in it, and for each tab I have created a panel so that the user will be in the same window when switching between tabs.
Tabs - Dashboard, Contacts, Summary, Profile 
A separate panel has been created for each tab, and on the panel Paint() function i have a async task that is executed to get the data from the database.The problem I'm having is that each time the i switch between the panels all the panels run the async tasks to get the data from the database. Where else can i call the async tasks so that the database call is not sent on each panel Paint().

This is the code I'm currently using

```
        private async void pnl_cont_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            var contacts = await Task.Run(() => dbHelper.getContatcs());
            this.AddControls(contacts);
            pnl_cont.BringToFront();
        }

        private async void pnl_summary_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            var summary = await Task.Run(() => dbHelper.getSummary());
            this.AddControls(summary);
            pnl_summary.BringToFront();
        }
```

I have 2 other add data forms an on AddData.FormClosing() i execture a method to remove all the controls from the panel and repaint, that is the only instance i need to refresh the data within the panel.

```
private void AddDataFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  this.pnl_summary.Controls.Clear();
  this.pnl_summary.Refresh();
  this.pnl_summary.BringToFront();
}
```

Should I do something like this

```
Summary summary = new Summary();

public void getSummary()
{
  summary = await Task.Run(() => dbHelper.getSummary());
}


private async void pnl_summary_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{       
  this.AddControls(summary);
  pnl_summary.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: Only you know at which point in your application the data must be updated.

Comment: We need to see more code to help you. Is there an OnLoad(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) function where you can make your call to the database?

Comment: @GSerg I updated the question with the place i need to refresh the data and the function that im using to do it.

Comment: Getting data in Paint() seems extremely excessive. Why don't you get data only when a user switches to a tab?

Comment: @nickgowdy The Function async void pnl_summary_Paint is where i call the database

Comment: @xxbbcc I updated my question with a possible fix.Should I do something like this?